# "The last book I've read is" vs past-simple

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

I've troubles understanding why the tenses for the following sentence should be in the past:

> The last book I **have** read **is** Animal Farm, and it'**s** really good.

I've been corrected (*not from a native*), stating that, instead of using the present-simple and the present-perfect, I should use the past-simple:

> The last book I **read** **was** Animal Farm, and it **was** really good.

I understand that the past-simple for **read** may be preferred since it's a finished action in the past. But, that book still *is* the last book I read, and the book still *is* good.

If that book was a pizza, I may understand that you won't be able to eat it again, so it *was* good, but a book still *is*: unless I'm not sure anymore, or I don't have an opinion anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wish to convey the idea that of the several books you have finished reading, the name of the most recent is *Animal Farm*:

> The last book I read is called *Animal Farm*.

We say **read** (past tense) because the statement refers to an event completed in the past;  **last** makes the point that the book was the final book read in a series of books which began and ended in the past. **Last** does not imply any relevance to the present.  In fact, **last** could be said to exclude the present. Hence the present perfect is inappropriate.

You could also say

> The last book I read was *Animal Farm*.
>
> The last book I read is *Animal Farm*.

There's no clear case to be made for insisting on a past-tense predicate there.

Also, "read" suggests an act completed. If you wanted to say that the book you have been occupied with, not necessarily finishing it, you could say:

> The book I've been reading most recently is *Animal Farm*.

There, we can use the present perfect.

If you've finished it:

> The book I've read most recently is *Animal Farm*.

"Recently" looks at time from the point of view of the present. Hence, the present perfect is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I guess I thought of using present-perfect because I may be an avid reader, so in a sense I could talk in an "open point of view". (yup, I don't really know how to explain it with simple words). _edit_: For example if I said _this month_ the present-perfect should be okay (if the month isn't over yet).

Comment: Right. If the time-words exclude the present, you can't use the present perfect.  You could say "this month", "this year", "this decade", even "this millenium" and still use the present perfect.  The **this** links the statement to the present.

Comment: But "last" would conflict  with "this".  "The last book I've read this week" would have a time-clash.

Comment: That "_last_" conflict with "_this_" is a game-changer for me! I've never thought about it, I just assumed it didn't create problems with _this_. Is there an obvious way to say _this week I've read A.F._  _implying_ it's the last one? I could say _"[...] and I've yet to decide the next one"_, but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: The last/this conflict is only under certain circumstances, when "this" refers to the present.  At 4PM, "*this* morning" refers to the past. "This morning" becomes the past at 12:01 :)

Comment: @drM. The present perfect considers a long period of time up to the present, the past simple does not. Compare: 1) *I've seen John this month*  = from the beggining of the month up to the present. 2) *I saw John this month = Earlier this month or last 2 weeks.*

Comment: "Is there an obvious way to say this week I've read A.F. implying it's the last one?"  "Most recently" is what you want to say in that case. The book I've read most recently is A.F.

Comment: I have just finished reading the book.You can take it now.